# Elegant way to check whether two Strings are different

Tags: c#, java, string-comparison

Is there an elegant way to compare two `Strings` and check whether they are different? For example in `Java`, I usually use something similar to this:

```
if (text1 != text2 || (text1 != null && !text1.equals(text2))) {
    // Texts are different
}
```

This is something so common that I was wondering maybe there is a better way.

**Edit:**
Ideally I want a pseudo code applicable to most common object oriented languages.

Comment: In general, please try to restrict your question to one language tag; otherwise it makes it quite hard for anyone to give a comprehensive correct answer.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want Java or C# code.

Comment: Ideally I want a pseudo code applicable to many object oriented languages.

Comment: As your question relies on particular mechanisms of a language you can't expect pseudocode applicable to many languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java 7+, you can use [`Objects#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
if (!Objects.equals(text1, text2))
```

Under the hood, it does something similar to the code in your question:

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

---

Note that **your code is broken in Java** by the way: it will return false in this case:

```
String text1 = "abc";
String text2 = new String("abc");
if (text1 != text2 || (text1 != null && !text1.equals(text2))) {
    System.out.println("Ooops, there is a bug");
}
```

The proper way to write a `isNotEquals` condition would be:

```
if (text1 != text2 && (text1 == null || !text1.equals(text2)))
```

Comment: `Objects` is not a standard Java class. Can you please tell us which library this is contained in?

Comment: @UwePlonus It is part of the JDK since Java 7. Added a link.

Comment: Could be improved by specifying "In Java 7+, ..." instead of refering to the bottom of the page ;)

Comment: @fge Java 7 being the current official version (and Java 6 being EOL), a footnote seemed good enough! Amended anyway!

Comment: @assylias save for the fact that a lot of deployments out there still use Java 6... Too many, but that's a fact

Answer (score 3):

This (C#):

```
if(text1 != text2){
}
```

should do the trick as the == operator and the != operator are overloaded to do a proper string compare.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What about whitespace characters?

Comment: This works in C# for comparing strings. The question includes the C# tag so you shouldn't downvote answers for C#. However, you might need to add `text1 != null &&` to the condition to make it exactly the same as the OP.

Comment: Please include the language your answer is for

Comment: @wonko79 BTW Ignore my last sentence, it's wrong - your code will work fine just as it is.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The `text1 != null` part is only used, so that `text1.equals(text2)` doesn't crash. I think the `==` and `!=` operators already consider the `null` case.

Comment: @Nolonar Aye, I realised that on closer inspection.

Answer (score 3):

Java (7 onwards):

```
Objects.equals(first, second);
```

C#:

```
string.Equals(first, second);
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# personally i use the above

```
If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text1) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text2) && (text1 != text2 )))
 {}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `text1 != text2` or `!text1.Equals(text2)`?